# Storing salt and hashed password

Tags: passwords, hash, salt, storage

Is there a benefit to storing salt appended to hashed password in a single column of a table verses storing salt and hashed password in different columns of the table. The OWASP guide here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet says 'Store the protected form appended to the salt as follows'

[protected form] = [salt] + protect([protection func], [salt] + [credential]);

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no difference between appending them in a single field or using different fields in the db. Use whatever you find simpler in your code or more consistent with your style. Conceptually, you may prefer to treat them as two different entities, while often you simply treat that field as a black box than only some inner functions use (and know how to split). It really doesn't matter the way you choose.